# MATLAB: get index of minima in 3D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d, minimum

i have a little question about MATLAB.

I have a 3D-array where each 2D-layer is a picture. What i need is the "third" index (=the number of the layer) of the lowest value for each pixel in this array. At the end i want to have a 2D array where i have the index of these lowest values.

An example:

3D array with these 2 2D-layers:

layer 1:

```
3-5-6
1-4-2
7-5-2
```

layer 2:

```
1-8-2 
4-6-1 
9-2-5
```

The result should be the following array:

```
2-1-2
1-1-2
1-2-1
```

I hope you can see what i want to achieve, sorry for my bad English, I cannot really express my problem in words...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `A` be the matrix then you can use

```
[B, I] = min(A, [], 3);
```

Where `B` is the minimum values and `I` contains the indices. If you are not interested in minimum values you can use

```
[~, I] = min(A, [], 3);
```

For you example

```
>> A(:,:,1) = [3 5 6; 1 4 2; 7 5 2];
>> A(:,:,2) = [1 8 2; 4 6 1; 9 2 5];
>> [B,I]=min(A, [], 3)
B =
     1     5     2
     1     4     1
     7     2     2
I =
     2     1     2
     1     1     2
     1     2     1
```

Comment: Thank your for your fast response! This is exaclty what i was looking for, it works great.